# Real Time Data Import from Arduino to Matlab. What BufferSize? Why delay?

Tags: matlab, arduino, delay

I am using a Kitronyx Snowboard (it has an Arduino Leonardo) with the Matrix Sensor 1610. I want to read my data from the serial port directly into Matlab and visualize it.

I have two problems which I think are related:
First of all I can read the Matrix but with a delay. The longer I wait the longer the delay.

Second of all after a while I’ll always get:

Error using serial/fprintf (line 144)

Unexpected error: A timeout occurred during the write operation..

The bigger the InputBufferSize the longer I can plot my data (which doesn’t really matter because of problem one)

How do I know what’s the convenient buffer size? Has anyone any idea why the delay and how I can get rid of it?

Thank you so much in advance

Mike

```
close all                   %close all figures
clear all                   %clear all workspace variables
fclose('all')               %close all Files
delete(instrfindall)        %Reset Com Port
delete(timerfindall)        %Delete Timers

% setup serial

serialPort = serial('COM3');

command = 'A';

nrow = 16;
ncol = 10;
row_index = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
col_index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

% 10x16 = 160 bytes
lendata = 160;
BaudRate = 11520;
InputBufferSize = 115200;
Timeout = 5;
set(serialPort , 'BaudRate', BaudRate);
set(serialPort , 'InputBufferSize', InputBufferSize);
set(serialPort , 'Timeout', Timeout);

fopen(serialPort);

while 1

% Request data
fprintf(serialPort, command);

% Get data
%Data is read as string (CSV)
data_string = fgets(serialPort);
data_string_array = strsplit(data_string, ',');
data = str2double(data_string_array);

% Reshape data (1D -> 2D array)
data2d = zeros(nrow, ncol);
k = 1;
for i = 1:nrow
   for j = 1:ncol
      data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = data(k);
      k = k + 1;
   end
end

%resize 16x10 image to 160x100 image
data2d_resized = imresize(data2d,50);
imshow(data2d_resized,[0 100]);

end
```

Comment: When you say 'the longer I wait the longer the delay', do you mean the longer the Timeout the longer the wait?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the instrument you are controlling is expecting a termination character and/or is sending a termination character that Matlab is not detecting...

Comment: No I mean in the first 10sec I can see my data transferred with a shorter delay than after a min for example. So the longer I have my code running the longer I have to wait to see a response from my sensor. I am getting one matrix after another. Wouldn’t my matrix be scrambled if there was something wrong with the termination character? How would you detect it? Thanks so much for your help?

Comment: Hm... doesn't sound like the termination character is the issue then...

Comment: Can it have something to do with the InputBufferSize? I just put in a number to make it work

Comment: The default inputbuffersize is 512 bytes, so you can see that 115200 is quite a large value. To pick a good value for this, have a look at the size of the data returned by your successful read commands (maybe use serialPort.BytesAvailable?). If the size of the data returned is always the same, you should set your inputbuffersize to this size. If it varies, you should make sure the inputbuffersize is always larger.

Comment: What’s the disadvantage of a large input buffer size? Does it make my program slower or does it only take up more space?

Comment: Looks like a typo in the BaudRate ("11520" vs "115200").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we have enough information to give a definitive answer, but there are some considerations.

1) The input buffer is just memory that is set aside to hold data that is received at the serial port. Data fills the buffer until you remove it with a read statement (`fgets(), fread()`, etc). As long as the buffer size is larger than the amount of data you will receive between read cycles (see below), and it is a small number relative to the RAM available, it will not be a problem.

2) The command `fgets()` returns the line terminator characters with the string. You don't need these characters; consider using `fegtl()` or `fscanf()` instead.

3) The symptoms you describe make it sound like the Arduino is sending a more data with each iteration, or it is sending data faster than your Matlab program can process it. Your code is written in such a way that if more data arrives than you expect, you will not notice this until the input buffer is full and things start crashing.
Try printing the size of the data in the input buffer (`disp(serialPort.BytesAvailable)`) and the length of the string returned in each iteration.

If this is the problem, you may have to implement some flow control- have the Matlab program send a character back to the Arduino when it is ready for more data. Or read all the data from the input buffer in each read cycle, not just one line.

4) If matlab execution speed is an issue, consider replacing the "Reshape" loop with the [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) command. For loops are always slower than built-in functions.

Comment: Thanks so much. You are exactly right. The InputBufferSize was filling up more and more. So I put flushinput(serialPort) at the end of the loop and it seems to work fine.